# Radeon Pack Bundle - Wolfenstein 2 and Prey Code Delivery Method

Tags: steam, prey

I already have one of the game that comes with this bundle. Prey. I was wondering does the amd promotion give you a steam code to use? Or is it a single code and will not give you a free gift to use?

For reference this is pack I am talking about.

http://www.pcworld.com/article/3215127/components-graphics/what-are-radeon-packs-for-amds-rx-vega-graphics-cards.html

Comment: I think it depends on the retailer. For instance, you can buy [this bundle](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814202299&ignorebbr=1) on Newegg - last time I got a free game from Newegg, it was through Origin (the game was For Honor, a Ubisoft game).  I also got the Witcher 3 for free via Newegg once, and that was through GOG games.  So it seems to depend on the retailer/game.  Considering both of these games in the bundle are Bethesda's, it would probably be through [their store](https://store.bethsoft.com/)

Comment: The code is redeem on amd website. Not a real retailer code. In fact they have a website where you sign in and receive your codes here. So I have no idea how it is delivered. https://www.amdrewards.com/amdrewards/

Comment: Please stop putting the Wolfenstein New Order tag on this. That's not the game in the bundle. It's Wolfenstein 2, The New Colossus. (currently unreleased)

Comment: Then what tag should I use? I meant there isn't a colossus 2 tag. I can't create it either.

Comment: Typically, we don't allow tags to be made until the game is out, so none.  I don't think it really helps the question much anyway.

Comment: My problem is I would have to remember to go back and re-tag it once the game is released.